# What kind of Android view is this?

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view

**Background**: I am developing a professional android app to let people get medical, healthcare and cleanliness facilities right at their home. The home page is completed. I am developing the *Fix appointment* page to let the user fix an appointment with doctors in their locality. I have a category section which shows what kind of doctor you want to meet. I was thinking of checkboxes to let users tick the category like a cardiologist, dentist, etc. But that would have not been a good UX. Then I came across this image:

[image: Circle views acting like checkboxes]

They are custom views acting like checkboxes.

**The Question**: I exactly don't know what kind of views they are?

**My perception**: They could be buttons with custom use interaction, or maybe even checkboxes either with an image view in them. I don't know what they are. If you have any idea, please let me know how to achieve this kind of view?

Comment: This is not proper question. This would be buttons, checkboxes, radio butttons, imageview or tab layout. You can achieve same using those widgets with custom background.

Comment: You can use bottom navigation activity.

Comment: Thanks @DHAVALASODARIYA for replying. I know that I can do that. But I don't know what kind of view must be this to have a background. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @MMR Sorry but this cannot be done with bottom navigation as this is not at the bottom, it's in the layout

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA Also I want to update the available doctor's list when the specific views are clicked stating the doctor which can do the task. Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommended to use TabLayout or Radio Buttons. If I were on your place, I'll go with TabLayout(If it need to place in single line)

Comment: Thanks I too think TabLayout will do the work, I am going to try that

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA But wait, there will be cases when user can click on more than one item and that should be selected, will it be possible with `TabLayout`?

Comment: Okay. So you need to use check boxes for that. I thought you need single item selection.

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA Can check boxes have custom images in them? Can you please show me an implementation. I really need that urgently

Comment: I added answer. Please check that.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom check box.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_layout"/>
```

`checkbox_layout.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked_checkbox"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_checkbox"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked_checkbox"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: What should be the content of `@drawable/selected_checkbox` and `@drawable/unchecked_checkbox`?

Comment: It is simply the image for unchecked state.

Comment: Everything is working fine but how to change the background color of the selected checkbox and not the others

Comment: Why don't you add background color with image itself.? By doing that, you don't need to manage it separately.